# ECONNRESET while installing Angular CLI with npm

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, cmd, npm-install

While trying to install Angular CLI on a machine with no proxy set and flawless internet I get a following error:

```
4727 silly extract micromatch@^3.1.4 extracted to C:\Users\User\AppData
\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\micromatch-7d604bf4 (38763ms)
4728 timing action:extract Completed in 265532ms
4729 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-eb8de851d6fef93d.lock for C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
4730 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
4731 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 277531ms
4732 verbose type system
4733 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.18.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
4733 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err 
[...]
4739 error code ECONNRESET
4740 error errno ECONNRESET
4741 error network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.18.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
4742 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
4742 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
4742 error network
4742 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
4742 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
4743 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

It usually fails on extracting rxjs package. So far I've tried:

- Setting registry to a http:// version, but then it fails earlier, every time on is-number package
- reinstalling and updating npm/node
- clearing the cache after every single operation
- disabling the windows firewall
- starting the command line with administrator rights
- checked that proxy config is null

Nothing seems to be working. Do you have any ideas?

Edit: Maybe this will help, but when I've tried to update npm itself, it would hang itself immediately on rollbackFailedOptional, it managed to update itself only after changing the registry to the http:// version

Comment: When I visit `https://registry.npmjs.org/mime-types/-/mime-types-2.1.18.tgz` in my browser it works as expected

Comment: What is your version of `npm`?

Comment: npm 6.0.1, node 10.1.0

Comment: Can you try rolling back to an earlier npm version, like `5.6.0` and retry?

Comment: It's still the same. I will try to downgrade node too.

Comment: Apparently rolling back node to 9.8.0 fixed the problem. If you want to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrade towards a more stable version of node/npm.
To install a specific version of npm, e.g, `5.6.0`:

```
npm install -g npm@5.6.0
```

Comment: I mean, it was the issue with node, not npm itself, it seems, it was downgrading node that fixed it.

Comment: I understand. I mentioned downgrading `_node_/npm` in the answer. do you think I need to make it more clear @MichałSadowski ?

Comment: No, no, I'm just probably too hasty right now. Anyway, thank you!